# Ansible copr module offending line

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

I'm trying to do a dry-run of a small test script I've put together for `ansible` but I am getting an error.

The script is this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Enable peterwu/iosevka
      community.general.copr:
        state: enabled
        name: peterwu/iosevka
    - name: Enable taw/element
      community.general.copr:
        host: copr.fedoraincloud.org
        state: enabled
        name: taw/element
```

But, when I run the command `ansible-playbook ~/Documents/Ansible/enable_repos.yml --check`, I get *this* output:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.copr'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/[REDACTED]/Documents/Ansible/enable_repos.yml': line 5, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
    - name: Enable peterwu/iosevka
      ^ here
```

I have followed all the instructions from [here](https://fedora-copr.github.io/posts/new-ansible-module-copr). Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**: `ansible` and `ansible-galaxy` are both version `2.9.21`; both installed from the official fedora repositories. I used `ansible-galaxy collection install community.general` and re-running the latter command yields the following output:

```
Process install dependency map
Starting collection install process
Skipping 'community.general' as it is already installed
```

I haven't done anything other with `ansible-galaxy` other than installing it. Maybe the issue is there?

Comment: You forgot to include your ansible version info, but my actual question is: what is the output of running `ansible-galaxy collection list`, with emphasis on `| grep copr`?

Comment: `ansible 2.9.21` and the command `ansible-galaxy collection list` doesn't work; it only gives me four options to choose: 1) `init`, `build`, `publish`, and `install`...

Comment: I tried that locally with 2.9.21 and couldn't reproduce your experience, so I'd guess you have installed the collection as some user other than the one you're using to run `ansible-playbook`; since your ansible-galaxy is so old, you can use `ansible-doc community.general.copr` as a replacement for what I was trying to figure out: does your ansible install see the collection or not. Separately, although perhaps related: their "install from github url" is broken, so I hope that wasn't the one you used

Comment: I've added an *edit* to my question. Please have a look. Is my version old? I thought that `2.10` still wasn't out?

Comment: [v2.11, v2.10, and v2.9.22 are all released](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/releases), although confusingly their rebranding exercise means that ["ansible v3" and "ansible v4"](https://pypi.org/project/ansible/#history) are also out :sob:

Comment: So I just installed the `ansible-collection-community-general` from the official repos and now it seems to work. Kinda strange that it doesn't work using the command `ansible-galaxy collection install community.general`...

Comment: Good to hear; you can add and accept your own answer to let others know that you found the solution

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help and sorry to have wasted your time :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the command `ansible-galaxy collection install community.general` did not work for me, as it did not allow me to use the various modules.

What worked for me was to install the `ansible-collection-community-general` from the official repos.